# How to trigger async. validation in redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I am using `asyncBlurFields`. I tried following actions: `change`, `startAsyncValidation`, `touch`, `blur`. None is triggering the async validation. Then I read redux-form doesn't work well with hidden inputs, so I changed type to `text` and it is still not working. Only time when async. validation is triggered is when user blurs the element.

Is my only option to add `ref` to a form instance, dig out `asyncValidate`,  get all required parameters manually and call it myself? I hope there is a better way, I don't want to add lengthy hacks to many forms. And that is my question:

**How to easily trigger `asyncValidate` without calling it with all its parameters myself?**